Disable MySQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY while logging violations
We have attempted to upgrade a legacy database from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 in the hopes of bringing it up to current, but quickly experienced queries that failed with this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. We have removed only_full_group_by from sql_mode for the 5.7 database, but what we'd really like to do is have these queries continue to succeed, but log a warning so that we can gather a list of all non-compliant queries that our application is generating, and fix them at the source. This is less-than-straightforward because of our use of an ORM.
This is similar to what's described in Alternative to removing ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, except that we are looking to generate the list of queries to fix.

You say that you want these queries continue to succeed - but the point is that they are not (neccessairly!) succeeding. There may well be some further hack down the road which does something to the data that treats any resultsets that have been mangled by going through an aggregating query in some obscure way that "fixes" any problems? What's going to happen now? Who knows?

I've been through a few legacy apps in my time and the "it''ll be/"it can be" fixed later or "just get it out the door" attitudes are (ahem...) a common (although unfortnate) trait amonst programmers/project managers - many of whom are on contract and don't care about code quality.  There's also inexperience - my heart goes out to anybody that has to look at some of the code that I wrote in my ealry career! In short, there are no easy answers to all of this - just the slog of (as Bill Karwin said) a combination of thorough testing and code inspection! Best of luck! :-)

No, there is no feature of MySQL to produce a warning for queries that would violate ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
Either the query fails if you have that mode enabled, or the query does not fail if you have that mode disabled (though it may produce arbitrary results, the same as it did in MySQL 5.6).
The only solutions are:

Code inspection. You said this is not easy, I guess for the typical reason that the ORM obscures what the final queries are (one may wonder if ORMs are worth using since they make debugging and testing so non-straightforward).

Thorough testing. Enable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode in a test instance of your application. Exercise the app's features enough to make it run every query at least once. This will of course fail with an error when it hits the first query that violates the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enforcement. Then you know which query it is, and you must fix it. Then continue testing until you hit another one.
It's up to you to test your app methodically so you know you've tried every query.


I would do both. Use code inspection to identify the cases where the queries might have a problem. I.e., any queries that use aggregation. This should narrow down the scope of what you need to test.

If you:
Create a MariaDB replica from current data it will handle a MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 master easy enough (the same way as the MySQL docs say to provision a replica). Any MariaDB version, all features below are in the stable 10.5+ versions of MariaDB.
Configure MariaDB with sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY globally.
Using plugin_load_add=sql_errlog the datadir will contain a sql_errors.log log file with the queries and the SQL error.
To mirror the queries to both your production MySQL server and the MariaDB replica, you can use the MaxScale proxy in a mirror configuration between the two so both receive the same queries.
[mysql1]
type=server
address=127.0.0.1
port=3000

[mariadb2]
type=server
address=127.0.0.1
port=3001

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=mysql1,mariadb2
user=maxuser
password=maxpwd

[Mirror-Router]
type=service
router=mirror
user=maxuser
password=maxpwd
targets=server1,server2
main=server1
exporter=file
file=/tmp/Mirror-Router.log

[Mirror-Listener]
type=listener
protocol=mariadbclient
service=Mirror-Router
port=3306

ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-mirror/
While MariaDB and MySQL are diverging products, the ability to detect and log ONLY_FULL_GROUP by should be close to 100%, regardless if you continue the migration to MySQL 5.7 (or MariaDB that you just tested).

LOL — it's a toss-up whether that's more work than just the testing method I suggested! Points for creativity though.

Well I do try :-) Mainly showing off a few related technologies that can integrate, and while I totally do endorse that a comprehensive unit tests are a necessary component to being able to reliably develop or maintain a service, the lack of them is reasons like our OP searches for alternatives (or stick on very old DB versions as you've undoubtedly seen far too many times). In appreciation of the difficulty I wrote MDEV-35573 sql_mode errors to warnings as a feature request.
